# How to create an expression from a parameterized function which is compatible with EFCore?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I want to filter a certain entity by Name. But "Name" is ambigous, we could have a UPN, a logon name, a display name, a first name, a last name.
so I want to extract the lengthy Expression to a Function that takes the search string and passes it to the Expression like this:

```cs
public Func<string, Expression<Func<AuthenticatedUserModel, bool>>> MatchByName =>
        filter => x =>
            x.StatusId != StatusId.Deleted
            && x.StatusId != StatusId.Unprepped
            && SupportedRecordTypes.Contains(x.RecordType)
            && x.LogonName.ToLower().Contains(filter.ToLower())
            && x.DisplayName.ToLower().Contains(filter.ToLower())
            && x.Email.ToLower().Contains(filter.ToLower())
            && x.Upn.ToLower().Contains(filter.ToLower());
```

now if i evaluate this query against EFCore almost everything works fine, but my `filter` parameter is an empty string!

it then gets called like this

```cs
public IQueryable<UsernameResponse> GetNamesLike(string filter)
    {
        return _dbContext.AuthenticatedUsers
            .Where(MatchByName(filter));
    }
```

how do i make this example work?

genrated code looks like this

```
DECLARE @__p_1 int = 50;
DECLARE @__ToLower_0 nvarchar(4000) = N'1027';

SELECT TOP(@__p_1) [w].[LogonName], [w].[DisplayName], [w].[Id]
FROM [dbo].[WebUserAuthenticatedUsersView] AS [w]
WHERE ((((([w].[StatusId] NOT IN ('139ed76b-a8bc-4f46-91aa-63e6efd4be56', '14d5a731-d03b-414f-890c-7fab2fedea6a') AND [w].[RecordType] IN (1, 0, 4)) AND ((@__ToLower_0 LIKE N'') OR (CHARINDEX(@__ToLower_0, LOWER([w].[LogonName])) > 0))) AND ((@__ToLower_0 LIKE N'') OR (CHARINDEX(@__ToLower_0, LOWER([w].[DisplayName])) > 0))) AND ((@__ToLower_0 LIKE N'') OR (CHARINDEX(@__ToLower_0, LOWER([w].[Email])) > 0))) AND ((@__ToLower_0 LIKE N'') OR (CHARINDEX(@__ToLower_0, LOWER([w].[Upn])) > 0))) AND ([w].[RecordType] <> 4)
```

---

Edit, this questions was stupid and i'm sorry. the filter arguemnt was never passed as empty string, it had the correct value from the start and i was just misreading the SQL it produced. I was looking for the search string in the actual query but it was passed as a parameter and all i read in the mody was N''

thanks for all who put effort in this question

Comment: `x.LogonName.ToLower().Contains(filter.ToLower())` <-- This is _not_ how you should be doing do case-sensitive string searching (both in for Linq-to-Objects and Linq-to-Entities).

Comment: of course i meant the parameter "filter" updated the question. and yes i know i should be using Ignore Case Culture, but this won't solve my problem^^

Comment: Your post doesn't show us how you're using `MatchByName`.

Comment: well obviously i'm just calling MatchByName(filter) 
giving a constant will probably have the same effect, in my case i'm having a function parameter, which is sent by a controller which has this as an optional parameter

Comment: So your code makes an explicit call to `MatchByName` somewhere... but what does it do with the returned `Func`?

Comment: Show real usage, probably i have solution.

Comment: edited the question again with the real usage

Comment: ...why is `MatchByName`  a func-returning-property instead of just a normal method that returns an `Expression<...>`?

Comment: i experimented a bit, there is no reasoning behind this. both does not work.

Comment: Show us how-and-where you're calling `GetNamesLike`. How do you _know_ that `filter` is nonempty? What does the generated SQL look like?

Comment: i debugged it, the generated SQL code looks like this (question updated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it as a function:

```cs
public Expression<Func<AuthenticatedUserModel, bool>> MatchByName(string filter) =>
    x =>
        x.StatusId != StatusId.Deleted
        && x.StatusId != StatusId.Unprepped
        && SupportedRecordTypes.Contains(x.RecordType)
        && x.LogonName.ToLower().Contains(filter.ToLower())
        && x.DisplayName.ToLower().Contains(filter.ToLower())
        && x.Email.ToLower().Contains(filter.ToLower())
        && x.Upn.ToLower().Contains(filter.ToLower());
```

Comment: already tried that, does not work too :(

Comment: I've done such things a hundred times, something not shown in the question. How do you use `GetNamesLike`?

Comment: i simply call it in a Where-Expression from the database context

Comment: It should work, I know how LINQ translator works. But if you really use this expression in this simple way - it is EF Core bug.

Comment: and i updated the question to show the function call

Comment: From generated query I see that everything is OK. Where is the problem? `(@__ToLower_0 LIKE N'')` is just part of predicate. `CHARINDEX(@__ToLower_0, LOWER([w].[Email])) > 0)` is important.

Comment: oh my god... i'm so stupid. yes, you're right, i totally misread the produced query!!! my mistake was on a whole different level, i'm incredibly sorry for wasting your time like this >.<